# I want to dynamically create a "dropdown" object. with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to dynamically create a "dropdown" object.
So I changed the element of "dropdown" using "jQuery".
It's a "dropdown" with a "hover" function, but when you click "hover" on the existing "dropdown" object, the focus of the "dropdown" object does not go out and "submenu" is visible.

But if I add the same html to the dom using "jQuery"
When I click "hover", the focus goes out and I throw it away.

It seems that "css" is not applied...

can i get help?

thank you

`

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>test</title>

</head>

<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed" data-panel-auto-height-mode="height">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
      <!-- Left navbar links -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a id="dropdownSubMenu1" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Dropdown</a>
          <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownSubMenu1" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Some action </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Some other action</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>

            <!-- Level two dropdown-->
            <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-hover">
              <a id="dropdownSubMenu2" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">Hover for action</a>
              <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownSubMenu2" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
                <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a>
                </li>

                <!-- Level three dropdown-->
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a id="dropdownSubMenu3" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">level 2</a>
                  <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownSubMenu3" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">3rd level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">3rd level</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- End Level three -->

                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- End Level two -->
          </ul>
        </li>
        <div id="topScreenList">
        </div>
      </ul>
      <!-- Right navbar links -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-widget="fullscreen" href="#" role="button">
            <i class="fas fa-expand-arrows-alt"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- /.navbar -->

    <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
      <!-- Brand Logo -->
      <a href="/" class="brand-link">
        <img src="" alt="Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity: .8">
        <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">?</span>
      </a>

      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
        <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <a href="#" class="d-block">?</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- SidebarSearch Form -->
        <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="input-group" data-widget="sidebar-search">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sidebar" type="search" placeholder="메뉴검색" aria-label="Search">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-sidebar">
                <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
        <nav class="mt-2">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.sidebar -->
    </aside>

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper iframe-mode" data-widget="iframe" data-loading-screen="750">
      <div class="nav navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light border-bottom p-0">
        <div class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link bg-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">close</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-widget="iframe-close" data-type="all">all</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-widget="iframe-close" data-type="all-other">other</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="nav-link bg-light" href="#" data-widget="iframe-scrollleft"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav overflow-hidden" role="tablist"></ul>
        <a class="nav-link bg-light" href="#" data-widget="iframe-scrollright"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        <a class="nav-link bg-light" href="#" data-widget="iframe-fullscreen"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-empty">
          <h2 class="display-4">No tab selected!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-loading">
          <div>
            <h2 class="display-4">Tab is loading <i class="fa fa-sync fa-spin"></i></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Control Sidebar -->
    <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
      <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
    </aside>
    <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  </div>
  <!-- ./wrapper -->
  const test = `
        
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a id="dropdownSubMenu1" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Dropdown</a>
            <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownSubMenu1" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Some action </a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Some other action</a></li>

              <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>

              <!-- Level two dropdown-->
              <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-hover">
                <a id="dropdownSubMenu2" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">Hover for action</a>
                <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownSubMenu2" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
                  <li>
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a>
                  </li>

                  <!-- Level three dropdown-->
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a id="dropdownSubMenu3" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">level 2</a>
                    <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownSubMenu3" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
                      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">3rd level</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">3rd level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <!-- End Level three -->

                  <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">level 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <!-- End Level two -->
            </ul>
          </li>
  `;
  $("#topScreenList").before(test);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

`

jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/pyusLbgz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was bootstrap's javascript event problem.
Since events are not applied to dynamically created objects, they must be initialized with javascript.

```
// dropdown menu toggle function
function toggleDropdown($toggle) {
  $toggle.next(".dropdown-menu").toggleClass("show");
}

// when the dropdown menu is clicked
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // stop propagating click events
  toggleDropdown($(this));
});

// Close all drop-down menus when the entire document is clicked
$(document).on("click", function () {
  $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("show");
});
```